# How to count pages at a search results?

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I want to get page number at a torrent search result.
I use this to get page number from a site which contains static page number.

```
        string link = "http://www.ted.com/translate/languages/tr";            
        string htmlicer = kynkal(link);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(htmlicer);
        var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/p/span[2]");
        int pageCount = Int32.Parse(node.innerText);            
        return pageCount;
```

but when I tried the link "http://extratorrent.cc/search/?new=1&search=example";
and I get xpath "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a[4]" with firebug and it doesnt work.

I also tried to get the number 113 in "total 113 torrents found" to check everypage until I get 0 torrents found I couldnt do this too. So how can I get page counts for each search?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate it, or is this an issue with scraping a website? Good tip: `Total pages = Math.Ceiling(TotalItems/ItemsPerPage)`. Rounding up because if the last page is only half full, it still counts as a page.

Comment: @Flater I dont know the amount of totalitems. I want to get "3" as answer if I wrote "http://extratorrent.cc/search/?new=1&search=example" because it has 3 pages.  You are right but I cant get the total torrents count.  in this example how can we get the number "113"?

Comment: I'm going to be really honest here and say that I have no interest in scraping torrent sites while at work here. Getting it from the page is so open-ended, you can't really give a general answer. Now if you were to give the exact HTML snippet (or something simplified, yet structurally equal) with the question on how to extract a given value from it; that'd be a completely different question.

Comment: @Flater you mean like this ? http://pastebin.com/K3gwu7zj  the number 113 in "total <b>113</b> torrents found" or total page count to be extracted

Comment: I guess it works  with                                                                                                 var noden = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@style='vertical-align:top; padding: 3px 5px 0px 10px;']/b").InnerText;                                                                                              so we can use  Math.Ceiling(TotalItems/ItemsPerPage) is it possible to get page count directly?